# Existing async requests failing with network error when file/image picker opened on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, xmlhttprequest, mobile-safari

I have a project where I need to upload multiple images asynchronously. It was working great everywhere (Chrome, Firefox, MacOS Safari, Android Chrome, iOS Safari on an iOS simulator running 11.4). However, on my iPhone using iOS Safari (and a few other iPhones I tried all running 11.4) the existing requests were failing when I opened the image/file picker.

I've since distilled the problem down to some much more simple code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Upload Progress: <span id="status">Not Started</span></p>
    <p>Blob Upload: <button id="blobUpload">Upload Blob</button></p>
    <p>File Input: <input type="file" /></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is main.js:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#blobUpload").click(() => {

    const status = document.getElementById("status");
    status.innerHTML = "Started";

    // Create an array about 2mb in size (similar to an image);
    // and append it to a form data object
    const intArray = new Uint8Array(2000000);
    const blob = new Blob([intArray]);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', blob);

    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', (ev) => {
      const percent = Math.round(ev.loaded / ev.total * 100);
      status.innerHTML = percent + '%';
    }, false);

    request.upload.addEventListener('error', (ev) => {
      status.innerHTML = '<span style="color: red">Network Error</span>';
    });

    request.open('POST', '/upload', true);
    request.send(formData);
  });
});
```

If I click the 'Upload Blob' button and then don't do anything else, it works 100% of the time, never ever fails. However, if I click the upload blob button, then while it's uploading I click a file input (which is totally unrelated to everything else), choose one of the menu options (Take Photo or Video, Photo Library, or Browse), then either choose something, or take a photo, or even just hit cancel to go back, the uploading blob will fail about 1/3 of the time with a 'Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost.' error. It doesn't matter what is being uploaded, (image or blob or whatever).

[Here is a video showing what happens.](https://i.imgur.com/WiUajYW.mp4)

It's been 2 days of debugging this, and I've found NOTHING of interest in my research and believe me I've tried. Any help would be appreciated. Beginning to believe it may just be a bug with Safari.

Comment: Is it maybe a memory issue? I'm not sure how JS handles memory, but maybe `$(document).ready` is called whenever the page is coming into view again and so the method for `#blobUpload` is redefined so your form data get's thrown away in the middle of the upload? Just making a very, very wild guess, sorry if I'm completely wrong :)

Comment: @MihaiFratu thanks for taking a stab. Unfortunately that’s not it. The ready event handler is only called once.

Comment: What server are you using, nginx?

Comment: @pegasuspect The upload is just to a Node server (which is also serving this page). The upload destination is irrelevant though. This was originally a problem uploading to S3.

Comment: What version is your node.js?

Comment: The upload destination is irrelevant, but not the server which you are uploading to. Because your error might be about a configuration on your server. It must also have an error code. If you can share the error code it can also help people find the issue faster.

Comment: @pegasuspect Node version is 8.11.1. There is no error on the server. Just on the client "Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost."

Comment: It also makes sense that there would be no error on the server side as it appears that the client side is somehow terminating the request before it completes.

Comment: and apart from errors can you check if the request reaches to server? you can console log in the post method in node.js

Comment: The request is definitely reaching the server. Like I said, if I don't touch a file input on the page, the request will succeed 100% of the time. I can also see the request start (but not complete) if a file input is interacted with.

Comment: Finally, someone with the same problem as me. I have also been having photo upload issues using dropzonejs + ios where dropzonejs thinks an error has occurred and still have no idea how to fix this. Uploads do reach my server but it seems like IOS closes the ajax connection before a response is received *only if* the camera or file library is open (since nginx reports a 499 status with these requests). I know that this also pauses pending ajax requests so could that be somehow related?

Comment: Huh. Sounds very similar. I submitted a bug report to apple, of course haven't heard a thing. Still no solution :(

Comment: It must be IOS' default behavior when certain apps get placed in the background. I noticed that you can see the same issue when issuing a simple ajax request then immediately hitting the home button before said request completes. This is probably what happens when you open the file library or camera: it causes the browser to get suspended in the background (pausing any pending async requests and killing ongoing connections already running)

Comment: Seems plausible. The only thing that makes me think otherwise is the inconsistency of it. Seems to happen 1/3 of the time or so...

Comment: Just to give more info on this, I stumbled across this github issue where the user encounters the same exact error message I see if I attempt to debug ios safari: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/4279. Maybe it is a recent IOS bug?

Comment: @georaldc Didn't see this link earlier, but yes. Those do seem to be related...

Comment: Has anyone figured out the solution to this?

Comment: Not yet... It appears to be that safari goes into the background when you bring up the image picker and because it's in the background pending network requests will get canceled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this was a problem with Safari going into the background when the photo picker came up, and as a background app, existing network requests would often not complete. No easy work around for that. I've been testing iOS 13 and as far as I can tell this is fixed. Interested to see if anyone else with this problem can also verify, but I've been running tests on iOS 12 vs iOS 13 and it's consistently failing with 12 and succeeding with 13.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch the file picker etc and make it fail are you getting an empty file field in your form?

There's a [known bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184490) within Safari which will cause XMLHttpRequest uploads to fail if a form has an empty file field.

Comment: The file field is not part of a form that is being submitted... so this bug is different (if it is a bug which I'm pretty sure it is).

Comment: In the comments everyone reporting that bug seems to say it happens when attaching data using a FormData object. Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Well.. that whole bug resolves around sending FormData with an empty field. I'm not doing that in this case, and it doesn't matter if the file input is empty or full. In my case I have an existing pending request, and then I go open a file input that is in no way connected to the form. Somehow in the process of bringing up the UI to select a file, the pending request is killed. I get a crash even if I pick a file each time.

Answer (score -1):

The answer here could lie with not fixing the error, but with better UI/UX.

While the file is uploading, you can disable the file picker button.
You can have also have a cancel button beside the (disabled) file picker button that shows up while something is uploading, just in case the user decides to cancel the upload.

And if you need to upload multiple files, let it all be stacked up and you can run a single upload that sequentially uploads all the files.

Comment: It's not a UI/UX problem. I have up to 28 file upload fields. If they start an upload on one of them, I don't want to block all the other 27 until that one is complete. I also want to be taking advantage of all the time they spend on this form to upload images in the background. Running all the uploads at the end takes forever (a current problem with the existing design), but having them go while the form is being filled out means that by the time the form is done most of the images have been uploaded.